# Batch file to run color from .dat

Tags: batch-file, colors, command

I made a LAN chat thingy, and want changeable colors (only by admin)
this is what i did:

(In the read batch)

```
@echo off

type color.dat
:read
cls
type log.dat
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
goto read
```

(in the admin batch)

```
:color
cls
echo Set new chat color:
echo 0 = black  a = L green
echo 1 = blue   b = L aqua
echo 2 = green  c = L red
echo 3 = aqua   d = L purple
echo 4 = red    e = L yellow
echo 5 = purple f = L white
echo 6 = yellow 
echo 7 = white  
echo 8 = gray   
echo 9 = L blue 
set /p clr= : 
echo color %clr% > color.dat
timeout /t 2 /nobreak
echo New color set!
pause >nul
```

I want to run the color.dat as a command, example: color 4e > color.dat -----OTHER FILE------- type color.dat I want it to run color.dat as the given color by the admin (im not very good in explaining :|) i want it to work in mutiple batch files in the same directory..

(Solved)

Comment: your grammar is great. Suggestion: it helps if you can explain the expected behavior and why your code is not meeting you expectations, ie what is wrong with it / errors its producing

Comment: I want to run the color.dat as a command, example:  
color 4e > color.dat
-----OTHER FILE-------
type color.dat

I want it to run color.dat as the given color by the admin
(im not very good in explaining :|)
i want it to work in mutiple batch files in the same directory...

Comment: Please put that extra info into the question by editing the post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to write to a file:

```
echo @color %clr% > color.cmd
```

to execute it:

```
call Color.cmd
```

NOTE: as you are writing a batchfile, it's Extension has to be `.cmd` or `.bat`

Note: `@` supresses command Repetition (I assume, you don't want to see the command on the Screen)

Comment: Thank you, i tried it and it worked!                                                            
now my humble LAN chat has a little more color!